# c++ / RSA convert key

Tags: c++, openssl, rsa, x509, der

I'm trying to encrypt something with RSA.

But my rsa libary doesn't seam to be able to use x509 keys.
So i tried to convert it to a DER key using openssl.

but i don't really understand how it works. i spotted two classes that seemed ok but i can't figure out how to use them.

the function are :

-i2d_X509

-X509

I did find a piece of code, but i can't understand it :

```
 int len;
 unsigned char *buf, *p;

 len = i2d_X509(x, NULL);

 buf = OPENSSL_malloc(len);

 if (buf == NULL)
      /* error */

 p = buf;

 i2d_X509(x, &p);
```

If you could help me out it would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`i2d_X509` means convert `X509` object from internal representation (which is `X509` structure) to DER encoded representation (which is copied over a buffer or in file).

So, in this code in line

```
len = i2d_X509(x, NULL);
```

you are determining the length of buffer or number of bytes required to represent the given certificate in DER from.

Then, you are allocating that much memory and final statement

```
len = i2d_X509(x, &p);
```

copies the `X509 *` certificate into this buffer in DER format.

This buffer you can persist in the file and save it as a certificate file say .cer, .crt and can open with any certificate tool.

Coming back to your problem, you can use this buffer into your program which accepts DER certificate.

But you mentioned key, did you?

If you need `RSA` public key, then you can do the following.

You may need to extract the key first by using `X509_get_pubkey` which will give key in `EVP_PKEY` structure.

```
 EVP_PKEY * pkey;
 pkey = X509_get_pubkey(x);

 RSA * rsa;
 rsa = EVP_PKEY_get1_RSA(pkey);
```

Now, output this `RSA` structure into DER.

```
int len;
unsigned char *buf, *p;

len = i2d_RSAPublicKey(rsa, buffer, buffer_length);
```

Allocate `buffer` to sufficient large length say 4000 depending on the key.

I think this would help you.

Comment: Don't forget to free the ```RSA*``` by calling ```RSA_free``` !